# I'm trying to order divs in html based on the id of them

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, button

I have a div, with lots of other divs inside, each with a button inside that. I need to order the divs inside the main div, based on their id, but without using jQuery or anything, just clean and simple JavaScript. I can't find any way to do this, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have been on lots of websites that show solutions for doing it based on the text within the div but not by the id.

```
function sortDiv() {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("divsGroup");
    var divs = mainDiv.children;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length(); i++) {
        if //divs[i] is higher in the alphabet than divs[i+1] then  {
            //rearrange the divs 
        };
    };
};
```

I need the divs to be rearranged so they're displayed based on their id, alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution where the sorting bit is handled in a simple Array of `id` strings. Then, for each `id` (already in alphabetical order), we loop through the divs to find the next one to (re-)insert into the DOM.

```js
document.getElementById("sortBtn").addEventListener("click", sortDivs);

function sortDivs(){
  let mainDiv = document.getElementById("divsGroup"),
      divs = mainDiv.children,
  // `[...divs]` converts `divs` to an Array so we can use the `.map` and `.sort` methods
  divsArray = [...divs];
  // `.map(div => div.id )` makes a new Array of all the `id` strings, and
  // `.sort()` sorts the new Array alphabetically
  idList = divsArray.map(div => div.id).sort();

  //console.log(idList); // logs ["a", "b", "c", "d" ]

  // `idList` and `divsArray` are Arrays, so we can also use 
  //    the `.forEach` method to loop through them
  idList.forEach(id => {
    // As we process each `id` alphabetically, we check each `div`'s id for a match 
    divsArray.forEach(div => {
      if(div.id == id){ // Finds div with matching id
        mainDiv.appendChild(div); // Moves the matching div to bottom of `mainDiv`
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="divsGroup">
  <div id="d">-d-</div>
  <div id="b">-b-</div>
  <div id="c">-c-</div>
  <div id="a">-a-</div>
</div>
<button id="sortBtn">Sort 'em</button>
```

Note: This code could be shorter, but for anyone unfamiliar with the `.map` and `.forEach` methods of Array, or with the spread operator (`...`), this lengthier version may help make things more clear.

Comment: That's great!! After a bit of fiddling (way less than the other submissions which didn't end up working), I got it working perectly. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript arrays sort to sort nodes like this:

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="9"><button>9</button></div>
  <div id="2"><button>2</button></div>
  <div id="3"><button>3</button></div>
  <div id="4"><button>4</button></div>
  <div id="5"><button>5</button></div>
  <div id="1"><button>1</button></div>
  <div id="6"><button>6</button></div>
  <div id="7"><button>7</button></div>
  <div id="8"><button>8</button></div>
</div>
```

```js
let parentNode = document.getElementById("main");
var e = parentNode.children;
[].slice
  .call(e)
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
  })
  .forEach(function(val, index) {
    parentNode.appendChild(val);
  });
```

Like this you can sort by any attribute, for example you can sort by textContent of those elements or any other property.
here's a pen: https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/XvpWBg
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`mainDiv.children` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Convert that to an Array and perform a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
Array.from(divs).sort((a,b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1)
```

Then loop through to move them into the `divsGroup` in order using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```
Array.from(divs).sort((a,b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).forEach(ele => {
    mainDiv.appendChild(ele);
});
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/g8n39v60/18/)</kbd>

Resulting `sortDiv()` function:

```
function sortDiv() {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("divsGroup");
    var divs = mainDiv.children;

    Array.from(divs).sort((a,b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).forEach(ele => {
        mainDiv.appendChild(ele);
    });
};
```

Alternatively, if you need the list copied to a new element instead of moved use [`cloneNode([deepcopy])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
Array.from(divs).sort((a,b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).forEach(ele => {
    someOtherDiv.appendChild(ele.cloneNode(true));
});
```